# Multiply/add initial number to get target number

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have a target number `n` e.g. 5, and I always start from the number 1 and I have to `*2` or `*3` or `+1` to it until I reach `n`. So in this case I would `*2` twice, then `+1` to get 5.

I am supposed to find the least number of operations to reach the target value. I see a similar question being [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009720/algorithm-to-reach-a-number-in-a-fixed-amount-of-steps-using-addition-division) but that requires a fixed number of steps while I have to figure out the least steps. Are there any tips on how I can tackle this problem?

This is a homework problem.

Comment: could we write a number like `15` as `(2*2+1)*3` or it must be `2*2*3+1+1+1`?

Comment: How big is `n` here? If it's in the hundreds of thousands, then you could probably still get away with the DP approach

Comment: It's at most a hundred thousand.

Comment: @Lrrr The former should be fine.

Comment: @maregor Please see my updated answer about how to output the operations of getting target.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be regarded as **search** or **DP** problem (yes in essence they are both related to ***state transition***), the key point is to define search state condition, suppose `n` is positive, here we define `f[i] = inf, inf is a really large integer` means number `i` is not reachable, `f[i] = k, k >= 0` means number `i` can be reached in at least `k` steps.

If `n` is not so large, we can use an array to store least steps for each number from 1 to n. The initial is that `f[1] = 0` and `f[i] = inf, 2 <= i <= n`. If we need to output how we get the target(ex, output of 5 is `1 2 4 5`), we can use another array `pre` to store the operations, define `pre[i] = j` means number `i` is produced by number `j`(ex, `pre[4] = 2` means number 4 is produced by number 2, because 2*2=4; `pre[3] = 1` means number 3 is produced by number 1, because 1*3=3):

```
    int inf = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    f[1] = 0;
    pre[1] = -1; // pre[i] = -1 means i is the start point
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++) {
        f[i] = inf;
        pre[i] = -1;
    }

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) { // since each number is positive so smaller number cannot be produced via larger number, no need to consider > n issue
        if(f[i] == inf) {
            continue;
        }
        if(2*i <= n && f[i] + 1 < f[2*i]) {
            f[2*i] = f[i] + 1;
            pre[2*i] = i; // means number 2*i is produced by number i
        }
        if(3*i <= n && f[i] + 1 < f[3*i]) {
            f[3*i] = f[i] + 1;
            pre[3*i] = i;
        }
        if(i+1 <= n && f[i] + 1 < f[i+1]) {
            f[i+1] = f[i] + 1;
            pre[i+1] = i;
        }
    }
```

The answer is `f[n]`.

How to output how we get target, we use the `pre` array to recover the operations:

```
        curr = n;
        pos = 0;
        ans[pos] = n;
        while(pre[curr] != -1) {
            pos++;
            ans[pos] = pre[curr];
            curr = pre[curr];
        }
        for(int i=pos;i>=0;i--) { // reverse order to output
            System.out.println(ans[i]);
        }
```

While if `n` is very large, you may need to use a priority queue to maintain state transition and a hash set to maintain least steps for each number.

Comment: I'm not sure if this algorithm give best result or not, but this was nice in my opinion :)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I thought of it as a graph with edges between nodes that represent +1, *2 or *3, and the run a BFS with S=1 and T=n. +1 from me.

Comment: @Lrrr The algorithm maybe not the best performance, but it can always get correct answer:)

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to go here is to work backwards. Start from `n` and try the action that reduces it the most, then the second one in the list etc. The code could look something like this:

```
string actions = "";
int i = n, count = 0;

while (i > 1)
{
    count++;

    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {    
        i = i / 3;
        actions = "*3 " + actions;
        continue;
    }

    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {    
        i = i / 2;
        actions = "*2 " + actions;
        continue;
    }

    i--;
    actions = "+1 " + actions;
}
```

Essentially, the idea is to get to `n` *as fast as possible*. I am not sure this the least amount of steps, but it does seem like a good start.

Comment: Eg: Given n = 10 , Your way –> 10 /2 = 5 -1 = 4 /2 = 2 /2 = 1 ( 4 steps ).
But the optimal way is –> 10 -1 = 9 /3 = 3 /3 = 1 ( 3 steps ).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the AI approach?

Think of you problem as a search in a tree: the root is 1, and every node X in the tree has 3 sons: 2*X,3*X,X+1.

you can either build the whole tree (every node X where X>n shouldn't have more sons) and use [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to find the shortest path from the root to a node that has the value n, or use [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) algorithm in case the graph does not fit into memory.

Comment: This is not a bad idea, but if `n` is big enough, this could be a long computational task...

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov got another idea with less than O(n) complexity?

Comment: What you suggested is not O(n). Please see my answer.

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov I see what you meant. However as suggested in your post, the fastest way is not always the shortest (least amount of steps).

e.g. with your code for 28:
`((1*2*3)+1)*2*2 -> 5 steps`
however the optimal is:
`(1*3*3*3)+1 -> 4 steps`

Comment: You are 100% right. This question is a classic example where DP is better than brute force. See @coderz 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the guaranteed shortest path.

```
static int result(int a, int b){
    int answer = 0;
    while (a < b){
        if (b % 3 == 0 && b / 3 >= a){
            b = b / 3;
            answer++;
        }
        else if ((b - 1) % 3 == 0 && (b - 1) / 3 >= a){
            b = b - 1;
            b = b / 3;
            answer += 2;
        }
        else if (b % 2 == 0 && b / 2 >= a){
            b = b / 2;
            answer++;
        }
        else{
            b = b - 1;
            answer++;
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```